# Black spot on leaf of cardboard cycad (zamia furfuracea)

Tags: watering, diseases, transplanting

I live in Korea.

I think that my precious cardboard cycad has some problem.

**Where the plant came from?**

- I purchased cardboard cycad on the internet. It was delivered in 36hr. When it was delivered, it was okay.

**How did I transplanted it?**

- After one week, I transplanted cardboard cycad to the larger **terracotta pot**. I used purchased soil from the gardener. Also, I gathered the pebbles( for the drainage, I spread it the bottom of the new pot) from the mountain. But the pebbles were sterilized using boiling water.

**How I managed it?**

- I placed the pot inside the house. The location of the pot in the house was 
  near the window of full-bright direct sunlight.
- I watered it whenever the top of the soil (3~4 cm deep) of the pot is completely dry.
- Temperature of the house is 15 to 20 degrees Celcius.

**So, What is the Problem?**

- At first, small black spot arises on the back side of the leaf. Like the picture on the below. (It is not brown fur of the cardboard cycad.)

[image: Black spot on the backside of the leaf]

- Then, gradually, the black spot gets bigger and bigger. And finally, center of the spot burns. At this point, black spot shows on the front side of leaf. It looks like the pictures on the below.

[image]
[image: Current status of cardboard cycad]

What do you think is the problem?
Is it my mistake? Or it is some kind of disease?